# Nice names in related objects in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am using Ruby on Rails with Active Admin and I have one model where there is relation to user model. Everything works, just instead of user email or something, it shows user object in select box when creating new object. For example:

```
<select id="playground_open_time_user_id" name="playground_open_time[user_id]">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="15">#<User:0x7fb553945628></option>
  <option value="44">#<User:0x7fb553943508></option>
  <option value="51">#<User:0x7fb553942ef0></option>
</select>
```

How and where could I change that it would show email or firstname + lastname instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try adding the method "name" to your model, something like :

```
class User
  def name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either add a method to your model, something like `pretty_string`, or add a view helper looking like `pretty_user_string(user)`. You'll then have to update your view to call the good method/function.

Answer (score 0):

The easy thing to do is to define a to_s method on your model object like so:

```
def to_s
self.first_name
end
```

Whenever ActiveAdmin encounters your object and it needs to display it, it will use the value returned from the method. It's pretty much like the toString() method that many Java frameworks use.